# Removing up button when opening settings with startActivityForResult in Pie

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, startactivityforresult, accessibility

I am opening the accessibility settings to let the user turn on my app's accessibility features. The code is as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

This works fine, but on Pie devices, there is an Up button and search button in the nav bar that I want to remove.

**Desired behavior (Android versions < 9):**

[image]

**Behavior in Android 9.0 and above:**

[image]

The trouble is that if the user presses the up button, they go back to the main settings app (instead of returning to my app). In either case, if the user presses the system back button, it functions as expected (they return to my app). I want to remove the back button in Pie so that the user won't be taken back to the main settings app. Is there a way to do this?